# Can the modal auxiliary verbs be considered to be in the present tense (form, not meaning)?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, modal-verbs, present-tense

According to *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan, modal auxiliary 
verbs do not normally have past tenses:

> The modal auxiliary verbs are *will, would, shall, should, can,
>   could, ought, may, might,* and *must*. Their grammar is different from
>   that of other verbs: for example, they have no infinitives,
>   participles or past tenses [...] Modal verbs do not have infinitives or
>   participles (*to may, maying, mayed* do not exist), and they do not
>   **normally** have past forms.

So can each modal auxiliary verb be considered to be in the present tense 
(in form, not meaning)? Since the modal auxiliary verbs are finite and they
do not have past tense forms (according to Michael Swan's *Practical English
Usage*), each must be in a present tense form.

Or are *will*, *can*, *may* and *shall* the present tenses (in form, not 
meaning) and *would*, *could*, *might* and *should* the past tenses (in
form, not meaning)?

What about the modal auxiliary *must*?

Comment: Does "Practical English Usage" only have one sentence saying something like "modal auxiliary verbs do not normally have past tenses", or does Swan give more explanation of what he means by that? I think it would depend on what you mean by "past tense".

Comment: @sumelic The following is a quote from Michael Swan's Practical English Usage: "The modal auxiliary verbs are will, would, shall, should, can, could, ought, may, might and must. Their grammar is different from that of other verbs: for example, they have no infinitives, participles or past tenses...Modal verbs do not have infinitives or participles (to may, maying, mayed do not exist), and they do not normally have past forms".

Comment: @sumelic By "past tense", I mean the form of the modal verb. I'm not talking about the meaning.

Comment: But toucans exist. Image from http://animals.sandiegozoo.org/sites/default/files/2016-11/animals_hero_toucan.jpg. ;-)

Comment: This essentially comes down to how you prefer to describe the language. Some would say that _can_ and _could_ are two completely unrelated modal verbs in Modern English which both have only one form; others would say that they are the morphological present- and past-tense forms of the same verb, which happens not to have any other morphological forms than those two. There are arguments for and against both views. There is no final, authoritative answer on this.

Comment: Can, may, etc aren't conjugated like normal present tense verbs in 3rd person singular, so treating them as present tense seems misleading: it's not "he cans", "she mays"...

Answer (score 2):

Getting back to the original question (asked 3 years, 8 months ago by someone who's left the group since), the actual answer is that whether you should consider modal auxiliary verbs to be inflected for tense depends entirely on what your grammatical system's definition of "inflected for tense" is, and how your grammatical system **uses** tense inflection.

For instance, some grammars of English insist that every sentence have a main tensed clause. Since modal auxiliaries can occur in simple sentences, these would have to be assigned a tense (typically Present, by default) by that grammar. On the other hand, your grammar might simply except modals from that requirement, or it might not have that rule at all, using something else instead.

No modern grammar that I know of distinguishes the historical present and past forms of modals (*may, can, shall, will* vs *might, could, should, would, must*) in any useful way, so the various final -t's and -d's are merely etymological curiosities, like the a-'s in *awake, atop, aloft,* and *asleep*.

A semantic past-present difference shows up with *can/could* in the ability sense, and *will/would* in the deontic 'willing to' sense. Both past descriptions refer to repeated behavior:

- *When I was young, I could do 100 pull ups; now I can only do 99.*
- *When he was young, he would talk by the hour; now he won't say a word.*

But that's about it; there's no tense or meaning difference between *He might do it* and *He may do it* -- both are possible, and that's it. *Should* has a special meaning as a weak *must*, both deontic and epistemic:

- *She should/must go to the ball.* (weak/strong obligation to go)
- *This should/must be the place they mentioned.* (weak/strong likelihood)

and, in the US at least, *shall* is not used for the future like epistemic *will*, but rather is restricted to two very special and limited deontic question constructions:

1. First person **singular** question - an offer to do a favor for the addressee

   - *Shall **I** open the window?*
2. First person **plural** question - an invitation to do something with the addressee

   - *Shall **we** dance?*

And, as you note, there is no historic present tense for *must*, as there is in German, where modal auxiliary verbs are not defective verbs like English modals, but real strong verbs, with all their principal parts, inflected regularly for everything.

So, if your grammar (and every linguist creates their own grammar of their own language) requires English modals to have tense, **Voila!** they do. If not, not. If you prefer, some may have tense and others may not. Questions like this are not matters of fact; they're arbitrary, so you might as well take whatever answer you like. It's **your** grammar, after all.

Comment: “…your grammar might simply except modals from that requirement.” perhaps *exempt*?

Comment: _Exempt_ would work; but _except_ is the verb we get _exception_ from.

Answer (score -1):

Modals have neither a past tense nor a present participle.  Let's take the example of "can", in the sentence, "I can play the piano."  The past tense of can doesn't exist;  there is no such word as "can-ed".  To express the intention of "I 'can-ed' play the piano", you must paraphrase:  "I have been able to play the piano."  Similar workarounds are required for "may" ("I was allowed to play the piano.")  The lack of a present participle for modals poses the same problem, and requires the same tactic of paraphrase: "Can-ing play the piano makes me very happy" becomes "Being able to play the piano makes me very happy."

"Must" has no past tense. "Must-ed you have missed your son's ball game?" is expressed by, "Did you have to miss your son's ball game?".

There was a time when the Germanic origins of American English indeed regarded "could", "might", "should", and "would" as past tense forms of modals, but no longer (except for some uses of "could" as the past tense of "can").  SEE, http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/box-modals.html

Comment: What about "I could play the piano", for example in the sentence 
"Sally knew that I could play the piano" (which looks like a past-tense equivalent of "Sally knows that I can play the piano")? Is that what you mean by "some uses of 'could' "? Why doesn't it ever apply to "might" and "would"?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would interpret the guidance regarding can/could.  "Might" is the past tense of "may", but not in the sense of being permitted to do something.  "I may stay up until midnight" could imply that the speaker is contemplating staying up that long, or that the speaker's mother has given permission to the speaker to stay up that late.  In the first case "might" can certainly be used instead of "may", but it still means that the speaker is still considering how late to stay up, and does not render the sentence a statement of an action in the past.

Comment: In the second example, "might" substituting for "may" entirely distorts the meaning, destroying the sense of permission granted by someone other than the speaker.  It does not connote that the permission to stay up until midnight was granted in the past.

Comment: I'm sure the extrapolation of the reasoning using "may" and "might" will explain why "would" does not operate as a past tense of a "could" as an auxiliary modal.

Comment: VOA's website gives the example of "She might have been delayed", expressing a degree of  likelihood of an event which has taken place in the past.  On the other hand, "She may have been delayed" seems to have the identical meaning, but American Heritage Dictionary's usage panel overwhelmingly rejected the use of "may" in the past tense.

Comment: @Allen S. Thank you very much for your reply. Since the modal auxiliary verbs are finite and they do not have past tense forms, is each modal verb in the present tense (form, not meaning)?

Comment: The _can/could_ ‘exception’ (if indeed an exception it is) is parallelled in _will/would_: “She knows that I will be there” vs “She knew that I would be there”.

Comment: Modals are used in two senses, and differ between the senses in their use and formation of tense. Compare **(1)** A says to B “I will come.” to B. Later C asks B, “What did A say?”, and B replies “A said(past) that he would(past) come.” with **(2)** *Would you like a cup of tea?”* that expresses an unspoken subjunctive condition = *“If I were [now, or at some time in the future,] to give you one,* would you [now or at that time] like a cup of tea?” Here, **would** is used to express a present/future possibility/probability, i.e. a degree of uncertainty.

Comment: Consider "Roland Kirk could play three horns at once until he had a stroke" and "Her mother said she might stay up until midnight."  The first of these seems to me to be a modal in the past and the second would have been and still might be considered a modal in the past tense in Southern Ontario. (I haven't been there in many years.)

Comment: You say *" The past tense of can doesn't exist"* and then you say *"(except for some uses of "could" as the past tense of "can")."* You should explain... "I can play the piano" -> "He said that he could play the piano."

Comment: @Greybeard "Could" is undoubtedly the preterite counterpart of "can" because it is the form required in backshift. It is just as much a preterite form as "opened" is of "open".