# Hello, I need help in understanding the grammatical tense of this phrase

Tags: tenses, sentence, articles

> It is easy to see how primitive warfare might sometimes have beneficial environmental effects; it is not clear how they could amount to a cause of primitive warfare.

Could you tell me, please, what grammatical tense is meant here, present or past tense?

Comment: Which verb are you asking about? Only verbs have tenses, and there are several verbs here.

Comment: "might" and "could". Do they indicate past or present tense?

Comment: What about conditional tense?

Comment: Syntactically, the primary tense is Present *(It **is** easy, it **is** not clear)*. And even the *modal* verb elements are essentially "present" *(might **have**, could **amount to**)*. But ***semantically***, it's obviously focused on the distant past *(primitive warfare)*. Logically, that focus on the past "should" be reflected by Past Tense / Conditional Present Perfect *(...might ... have **had** beneficial ...effects, ...how they could **have amounted** to a cause).* It's just that native Anglophones tend to avoid "unnecessary" Perfect verb forms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the modal auxiliary verbs be considered to be in the present tense (form, not meaning)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/423676/can-the-modal-auxiliary-verbs-be-considered-to-be-in-the-present-tense-form-no)

Comment: "Primitive warfare" here means war among modern "primitive" peoples (Oceanic societies etc.)

Comment: @Dmitry: Well, you're reading it, so I guess you should know. But I must admit I'm surprised that anyone can get stuff published today calling people (or their large-scale armed conflicts) "primitive".

Comment: Here is the whole fragment:

Comment: There is the old problem surrounding the fundamental premise of cultural determinism, to which the ecologists are heirs. The ecologists reify culture as thoroughly as Margaret Mead, speaking of it as an independent variable that is somehow superorganic. In addition they seem to reify ecology. They speak of ecosystems having "needs."

Comment: They speak of these evolutionary forces pulling the strings of human puppets - 
the warriors who believe they fight for pigs or honor or something - but receiving 
no input from the puppets. The basic theoretical problem is more serious than in 
the case of sociobiology because there is a body of generally accepted Darwinian 
theory that makes sociobiology at least theoretically plausible; but there is no 
such theory behind cultural determinism, and it is difficult to imagine just how 
ecosystems express their needs and how cultures respond to these.

Comment: It is easy to see how primitive warfare might sometimes have beneficial environmental effects; it is not clear how they could amount to a cause of primitive warfare.

Comment: I don't see anything in that "extended context" to suggest the writer is talking about *current* societies and wars. The use of Present Tense in, say, *the warriors who **believe** they **fight** for pigs* just looks to me like a vivid "presentation technique" intended to "bring the subject to life". And after all, the *underlying* focus of attention is "evolutionary forces" that have been active (if indeed the contextually relevant forces even exist at all) for many millions of years - nearly all of which timeframe is *well* in the past!

Comment: Modal verbs don’t have tense, but the sense of the sentence is “present tense” of the “general truth” type. The modal verbs provide a hedge on that truth. Roughly, you can swap in a **non-modal** to understand: *Primitive warfare [might] **does** have beneficial environmental effects; it is not clear how those effects [could] **do** cause primitive warfare.* --> *Primitive warfare  **has** beneficial environmental effects; it is not clear how those effects **cause**  primitive warfare.*

Comment: Many-many thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 0):

> It is easy to see how primitive warfare might sometimes have beneficial environmental effects; it is not clear how they could amount to a cause of primitive warfare.

I will assume you want help understanding the statement. A paraphrase:

> It is possible that primitive warfare sometimes has benefits for the environment; that is not hard to imagine; but what is not clear is how those environmental benefits could cause primitive societies to engage in warfare.

The sentence is silent on whether **primitive warfare** refers to the warfare of current-day primitive societies or of those primitive societies from the distant past, or both. It is a generalization.

**amount to a cause ...** means something like "could be so compelling a motive that primitive societies would intentionally go to war for that purpose, or unintentionally by virtue of being motivated by environmental forces they did not understand or even recognize."

The sentence is questioning how the environmental benefits of war could *produce* war.

Comment: I think *in principle* the cited text could just as well have used the "present tense" versions *(**may, can**)* instead of the "past tense" conditional modals *(**might, could**)*. The fact that the writer didn't choose to do this suggests to me he's not even *thinking* about "warfare" engaged in by *current* "primitives".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I would disagree. If the subject was exclusively past primitive societies, **might have had** and **how they could have amounted to** would have been the phrasings, or might well have been the phrasings.

Comment: But per my first comment under the question, most competent writers would avoid that unnecessarily complex verb form if they thought their readers would mostly make the same assumptions as me (rather than the OP here) regarding the primary temporal focus of the text's subject matter. And I'm a native speaker, which presumably means I'm part of the writer's target audience. The OP isn't, so it's unremarkable that he should make a different assumption.

Comment: ...I don't mean the writer would be *consciously* thinking that he's *only* concerned with *past* primitive societies. As you say, he's observing ***general (timeless)*** "truths".

Comment: @FumbleFingers   **primitive** doesn't always refer to the past. And **could have had** or **could have amounted** isn't that complex.  Do you have V8 tomato juice in the UK? There was a TV ad where people who are drinking some soft drink bonk themselves on the forehead with the heel of their hand and say, "I could have had a V8!"

Comment: I don't think this "disagreement" is going to get any further. I don't disagree with your penultimate paragraph. My disagreement is with the OP saying the writer is *specifically* referring to current "primitive" societies. Imho the writer isn't explicitly *excluding* current societies, but he'd probably prefer that particular issue to remain "vague, indeterminate".

Comment: ...also note that just because I say native Anglophones tend to avoid "unnecessary" Perfect forms doesn't imply they have a problem with *necessary* usages such as *"I could have had a V8!"* (in a context where where *"I could **have** a V8!"* would make no sense).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and explanations!